# Can these small Hall-Effect Current Sensor Modules really handle 30A?

Tags: pcb-design, current-measurement, hall-effect

These don't look like the could reliably handle 30A to me. The terminal block is small, the chip is tiny.

Please help me understand what the considerations are when sizing components & traces for high currents.

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/Tolako-Hall-Effect-Current-Sensor-Module/dp/B01FA36DKC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FA36DKC)

Comment: check the IC datasheet

Comment: This all depends on heat removal. The heavy wires into the terminal block may keep the R_shunt cool.

Comment: The IC datasheet says it's good for 30A but that surprises me, given the size of wire I'm used to seeing used for these kinds of current. Maybe I'm just used to thick cables used to prevent voltage drop over distance.

Comment: You got it right Jake, "voltage drop over distance", here you have very short distance= low voltage drop.

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet of the chip itself states it is rated to 30A with peaks to 100A.

The terminal block is probably not good for more than 10A. It is not apparent what the PCB itself would tolerate.